# How to SUM the data properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Have issue I cannot sum data in the right way. Do not know what is the issue and why query is not summing all the info.
Here is the query :

```
select m.store, SUM(s.salePrice) as Price ,s.Date, d.name
from market m
inner join distributor d on d.marketId = m.marketId
inner join sales s on s.distributorId = d.distributorId
group by s.Date,m.store,d.name
```

Outcome of the query :

```
   store   |  price  |     date      | distributor |
----------------------------------------------------
Store MAX    -10000     22-05-2019      RedBull
Store MAX     25000     22-05-2019      RedBull
Store Z      -2000      22-05-2019      RedBull
Store Z       15000     22-05-2019      RedBull
```

What I want as outcome :

```
 store   |  price  |     date      | distributor |
----------------------------------------------------
Store MAX    15000     22-05-2019      RedBull
Store Z      13000    22-05-2019       RedBull
```

Why SQL did not include (-) operators in SUM function?

If you can help please advice, thanks!

Comment: I think the problem might be in your group by part, could that be making it not computing the total?

Comment: Where is the column `distributor` in your results coming from? It's not defined in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, where you reproduce this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019

Comment: I can't replicate the problem; the data aggregates fine (if we assume that `distributor` in the data is actually the `name` column): [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75a14ca3931ab5a9855d886b2e887693)

Comment: Yep name is distributor

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, the above works fine; there's something you aren't telling us here, @nemd . You need to take the time to produce a [mre] as the above is not reproducible with the data you have given us.

Comment: nemd trim the spaces ltrim(rtrim(m.store)) and ltrim(rtrim(d.name)) both on the select and group by

Answer (score 1):

This would be occurring because something is not the same:

- The store names are not the same, but look similar.
- The dates are not the same.  Perhaps they have a time component, and that is not showing.
- The distributor is not the same.

I am guessing that the store names are okay, because they are looked up in the table.  You can check if only using that works by using aggregation functions on the other columns:

```
select m.store, SUM(s.salePrice) as Price,
       max(s.Date), max(d.name)
from market m join
     distributor d
     on d.marketId = m.marketId join
     sales s
     on s.distributorId = d.distributorId
group by m.store;
```

If this does not produce duplicates, then you know that `store` is okay and you can check the other columns.  When you find them, you will need to investigate the values to figure out how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

First replace the d.name to distributor from the "select" and "group by" as I do not see "name" field from your output.

Comment: Changing/converting the data type of a column in the `SELECT` won't affect how many rows are returned.

Comment: First replace the d.name to distributor from the "select" and "group by" as I do not see "name" field from your output.

Comment: Yes, I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222307/how-to-sum-the-data-properly/69222377?noredirect=1#comment122347856_69222307) on that, and the OP has [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222307/how-to-sum-the-data-properly/69222377?noredirect=1#comment122348340_69222307) that `name` is actually `distributor`. I *assume* it should read `d.name AS Distributor`.

Comment: I'm not the OP, Lenroy...

Comment: can you trim spaces